# Set width of a div to fit a specific subdiv content

Tags: html, css, width

I have a div containing an image, a title and a description.

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-header">
        <div class="item-header-image">
            <img src="img/items/15839.png" alt="Pile Steamer" width="80" height="80">
        </div>
        <div class="item-header-title">
            Pile Steamer
        </div>

        La seule façon de savoir si celle-ci est chargée, consiste à poser ses deux extrémités sur votre langue. Si vous perdez la langue, elle était chargée.
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the width of the `item-header` `div`, so that my image and my title fit in the `div` on one line (they are both `display: inline-block;`). But I don't want to make my `div` wider, and the description on the item may take up several lines.

I could set a fixed width that matches for a specific item, but it won't work with different title.

Can I set the width of a `div` to the width of a subdiv + `80px`? (80px is the width of my image.)

Comment: Can you provide your css?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the title and image that you want in one line inside a div, and give that div the `display:flex` style property. Here is the code I came up with and it seems to be working as you intended it to:

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-header">
            <!-- Item header line div -->
            <div  style="display:flex;"> 
                <div class="item-header-image">
                    <img src="img/items/15839.png" alt="Pile Steamer" width="80" height="80">
                </div>
                <div class="item-header-title">
                    Pile Steamer
                </div>
            </div>

            La seule façon de savoir si celle-ci est chargée, consiste à poser ses deux extrémités sur votre langue. Si
            vous perdez la langue, elle était chargée.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

On a side note, it would be easier for the community to answer your question if you provide the css along with the html.

Hope this helps!